# Bookhands (tgothic) package not rendering on Overleaf

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, overleaf, metafont

I've downloaded the handbooks package from CTAN at https://ctan.org/pkg/bookhands, compiled only the tgothic package locally (`latex tgothic.ins`) and uploaded it to Overleaf.
There I tried to render the `allgothic.tex` file, getting an error of `Bad metric (TFM) file`about the tgothic 10pt file definition.
I'm unsure about the changes that must be made to avoid the usage of the docmfp file and I fear that is the cause of the issue.

A `.map` file was added, but that didn't help either.

Can anybody help me figure this out? I've also tried to contact the author of the package, but the email provided with the documentation is no longer active. He is, however, active on here and I hope this post will get to him.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alltgoth}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

The error is on line `\begin{document}` and refers to the package allgoth, which is compiled by from the CTAN package.

I provide the full compile error with the `.map` file added:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.1.13)  18 JAN 2018 08:58
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**allfont.tex
(./allfont.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (./alltgoth.sty
Package: alltgoth 2002/12/30 v1.0 package for all Gothic Textura fonts

(./tgothic.sty
Package: tgothic 2002/12/30 v1.0 package for Gothic Textura fonts
)){/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{tgoth.map

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file tgoth.map): ambiguous entry for `tgoth7.mf': fon
t file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file tgoth.map): ambiguous entry for `tgoth10.mf': fo
nt file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file tgoth.map): ambiguous entry for `tgoth17.mf': fo
nt file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file tgoth.map): ambiguous entry for `tgothb7.mf': fo
nt file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file tgoth.map): ambiguous entry for `tgothb10.mf': f
ont file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present


pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file tgoth.map): ambiguous entry for `tgothb17.mf': f
ont file present but not included, will be treated as font file not present
} (./allfont.aux)
\openout1 = `allfont.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+tgoth on input line 35.

 (./t1tgoth.fd)
./allfont.tex:35: Font T1/tgoth/m/n/10=tgoth10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Bad metr
ic (TFM) file.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.35 \begin{document}

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 471 strings out of 493013
 4428 string characters out of 6135682
 53488 words of memory out of 5000000
 4085 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4403 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,0n,17p,157b,66s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

./allfont.tex:35:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Not supported in TeX Live? https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2011-August/030031.html

Comment: I have no clue how to answer your question, to be honest. Still hoping the author of the package may be able to help us

Comment: I don't know about overleaf. Please provide a LaTeX MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing how you tried to use `tgothic`.

Comment: @PeterWilson I'm glad you saw the post! I've added a MWE that, compiled on that particular software, issues an error.

Comment: I opened an issue with the Japanese TeX Developer Community (where I am also a member) https://github.com/texjporg/ptex-fonts/issues/2

Comment: Re-reading the first comment posted by Lim explains the problem. The original poster uses files that are not installed into the texmf-dist/tex tree of TeX Live, and thus should not be available.

Comment: @PeterWilson  Please join the conversation at tex-live@tug.org.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In collaboration with Peter Wilson I have updated the `tgothic` part of the `bookhands` package to fix this issue by renaming the `tgothN` fonts to `tgothrN` fonts.

Update packages are on CTAN and already included in TeX Live, where the `tfm` files are now also installed.

That means that with current up2date TeX Live compiling `allfont.tex` works.

Warning: The change of font name will break old `.dvi` files as well as old TeX files that refer to the fonts directly. Files using the `.sty` interface are not concerned.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think I am following you here. I've downloaded the package again from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookhands) recompile the files but they appear to be pretty much the same as before.
Trying them on Overleaf, the `allfont.tex` in the `tgothic` folder still is broken. However, that is probably due to the fact that they need to update their version of TeX Live?

Comment: Not all files are the same, the .sty files and the name of the generated .mf fonts are different. Look closely.

Comment: dear @norbert, now that the job freed me some time to spare, I got back to the issue. The updated package is available [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/bookhands/tgothic) and I confirm it works on Overleaf now. I will experiment all the other types in the `bookhands` package now.
Last time I checked, I probably downloaded files from a cache or something (I still have timestamps and all to prove it didn't work)
Even though it's not a good policy on this sites, I would heartily like to say thank you to you all.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a direct answer to your difficulty but it does point up a problem.

I use Ubuntu and on my TeXlive system there are no packages called `alltgoth` or `tgothic`. I looked on CTAN and couldn't find any package called `alltgoth`. I did find a package called `tgothic` which was said to be part of TeXlive but having just updated TeXlive on my machine it is not there. In my setup it should have been in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bookhands`. However in there are packages `allegoth` and `allpgoth` which do produce Gothic text. See if

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{allpgoth} % or allegoth
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

works for you, even if the font is not what you are after.

I know that I did the Gothic fonts and packages in 2002 but that's a long time ago and looking at some of the code now I don't understand it. My original coding has been lost with international moves and various computers. I'm sorry but I can't help.

There has been some discussion about this elsewhere. It appears that `tgothic` was a 1980's `ptex` package and my 2002 `tgothic` never made it to TeXlive. Norbert Preining has made suitable changes and renamings to 2002 tgothic (e.g. tgoth10 to tgothr10) that should soon be available on CTAN and then into TeXlive.

[EDIT 31/1/18] With my grateful thanks to @norbert Preining for fixing the problem. BTW would anyone like to take over the `archaic` and `bookhand` fonts from me?

Comment: I picked up on this from a post Peter made on c.t.t. I have the packages and fonts, and it looks as if the distribution tgoth10.tfm file might be corrupt. On my system they are in texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/ptex/standard, with .vf files in texmf-dist/fonts/vf/ptex/standard, but I don't know what ptex is; and there are .pl files in texmf-dist/fonts/source/ptex/standard as well.

Comment: @PeterFlynn ptex is a Japanese TeX engine that has been available since the 80ies. Japanese font metrics are uniform across fonts, that means there is only a few tfm files, one of which is tgoth etc. These have been in use since 40+ years. As Lim pointed out in the first comment, Karl has already realized that in 2011 and refrained correctly from creating problems by installing the gothic font tfms. They need to change the font name.

Comment: I've tested your snippet and it works just fine as expected. After reading the comments, I think I have a better grasp on the subject at hand now, and I am grateful for the time you spent both on creating the original package and replying to my question.
I would like to take on the packages, but I fear my skills are not yet on point to handle the unknown. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It seems ptex-fonts provides tgoth tfms that are picked up in lieu of compiling tgothic fonts from the mfs.  Try

> sudo tlmgr remove -force ptex ptex-fonts

unless you intend to write Japanese documents.